# Alternative to testing controllers in Spring 3.2.4

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, controller

In Spring 3.0.5 and before, it was possible to create a base controller test class that fetched the HandlerMapping object from the Spring Application Context to directly access and call into a controller's method via the URL. I found this approach to be really awesome because in addition to testing the controller's methods, I was also testing the path variables and such in my unit/integration tests.

With Spring 3.2.4, this approach appears not to be possible any longer due to the restructuring of how Spring deals with Url mappings. I see that Spring provides a new MVC test framework, but to be honest, I think it's design is too verbose and looks nothing like the rest of the framework or my application code. It also doesn't play nicely with intellisense features in IntelliJ. To be honest, I'd rather not use it.

So, is there an alternative way to test controller URL's that does not use the new Spring MVC test framework, like I was doing before? I have an existing project with 371 controller tests, and I'd REALLY like to avoid migrating everything over to use the Spring MVC test framework.

Here is the `handle()` method I was using to test controllers using Spring 3.0.5:

```
protected ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    final HandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerMapping.class);
    final HandlerExecutionChain handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
    assertNotNull("No handler found for request, check you request mapping", handler);

    final Object controller = handler.getHandler();

    final HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getInterceptors();

    for (HandlerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
        final boolean carryOn = interceptor.preHandle(request, response, controller);
        if (!carryOn) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
}

protected ModelAndView handle(String method, String path, String queryString) throws Exception {
    request.setMethod(method);
    request.setRequestURI(path);

    if(queryString != null) {
        String[] parameters = queryString.split("&");
        for(String parameter : parameters) {
            String[] pair = parameter.split("=");
            if(pair.length == 2) {
                request.setParameter(pair[0], pair[1]);
            } else {
                request.setParameter(pair[0], "");
            }
        }
    }

    return handle(request, response);
}

protected ModelAndView handle(String method, String path, String attribute, Object object) throws Exception {
    MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
    session.setAttribute(attribute, object);
    request.setSession(session);

    return handle(method, path, null);
}

protected ModelAndView handle(String method, String path) throws Exception {
    return handle(method, path, null);
}
```

Here is some test code illustrating how I was using the `handle()` method:

```
@Test
public void show() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = handle("GET", "/courseVersion/1/section/1");

    Section section = (Section) modelAndView.getModel().get("section");

    assertEquals(1, section.getId());
}
```

Here is my servlet application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:applicationContext.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="expressionHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    </bean>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </security:global-method-security>

    <context:component-scan base-package="keiko.web.controllers"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="keiko.web.interceptors.IpValidationInterceptor" />
        <bean class="keiko.web.interceptors.UnreadMessagesInterceptor" />
        <bean class="keiko.web.interceptors.ThemeInterceptor" />
        <bean class="keiko.web.interceptors.ApplicationMenuInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
        <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="auto_import">lib/common.ftl as common, lib/layouts.ftl as layouts</prop>
                <prop key="whitespace_stripping">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="freemarkerVariables">
            <map>
                <entry key="template_update_delay" value="0"/>
                <entry key="default_encoding" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
                <entry key="number_format" value="0.##"/>
                <entry key="xml_escape">
                    <bean class="freemarker.template.utility.XmlEscape"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contentNegotiatingViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="useNotAcceptableStatusCode" value="true" />
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
                    <property name="contentType" value="text/html" />
                    <property name="order" value="2"/>
                    <property name="cache" value="${freemarker.cache}"/>
                    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
                    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
                    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="contentType" value="application/json" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewNameTranslator" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator"/>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="keiko.domain.courseauthor.SectionIsDelayedException">error/sectionIsDelayed</prop>
                <prop key="keiko.service.director.CompanyHomepageClosedException">error/registrationClosed</prop>
                <prop key="keiko.service.director.IpDeniedException">error/ipDenied</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What `HandlerMapping` type is your bean?

Comment: In 3.0.5, I am not sure. There was only a single instantiation of it. You could get access to every controller in your application through here, as you can see in the code. Of course, it breaks in Spring 3.2.4.

Comment: No, I mean in your `ApplicationContext`, you use `applicationContext.getBean(HandlerMapping.class);` What type is the returning object? How are you declaring it in your context?

Comment: Unlike in 3.0.5, there are 3 different ones: RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, HttpRequestHandlerAdapter, and SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter. I don't think I am defining these. These are getting created by Spring under the covers I think.

Comment: Let's see your application context please.

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: This is why they introduced an MVC testing framework, so you wouldn't need to rely on the 'under-the-covers' stuff to get your controllers tested.  What happens when you change this, and then in Spring 4, they change things under the covers again?  Personally, I would just use the tools provided...

Comment: Well, the spring-mvc test framework is poorly designed and it is not pleasant to code with. It was a huge mistake for them to release that and make this the official test framework, when they knew people were writing their tests this way by the masses. It also makes it really difficult to upgrade an existing application to take advantage of new features in the framework. All that is really, honestly required in 99% of cases is the url call with the request method returning a ModelAndView object. Static methods upon static methods is not my idea of a simple approach to testing controllers.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it was poorly designed, but rather that it was intentionally designed that way...it is a fluent api!! :)  Granted, if you don't like fluent api's then that might be problematic.

Comment: It is counter-intuitive for Java code though, and IntelliJ offers no help with that kind of API without manual tinkering, such as manually importing the static methods, or writing out the full class/method, and then alt-entering to make that method call static. Writing conventional Java code is simply faster and more straight-forward, and I have basically never come across such an extreme case where this approach wasn't good enough. Sometimes elegance and simplicity is best. What they did was the worst. It's weighty and bloated and IDEA doesn't like it. It also forces me to rewrite my tests.

Comment: I am not trying to argue with you, just giving you the facts that I have.  Spring MVC Test is an intentionally built fluent api.  If that is something that you are unwilling to work with, that is fine by me.  Good luck in finding resolution to this issue of yours.

Comment: I wasn't trying to create an argument, but my question already stipulated that I don't wish to use it. Spring usually adopts the approach that the developer knows best, but in this case, it wants to jam a testing approach down my throat that I don't like, and I don't see why it couldn't have alternatives available. It is anti-Spring.

Comment: @egervari I've just written 450 tests using springs test framework, there is nothing counter intutive about it at all. There are only four static methods I used and they were the different request types : get,post,delete,put. It is far more counter intuitive to create your own unique test framework without making use of the already existing mocks. And btw this is simply false : "All that is really, honestly required in 99% of cases is the url call with the request method returning a ModelAndView object."

Answer (score 1):

Basically your test method has been flawed basically from the start. There was always a possibility that there where more then 1 `HandlerMapping` and 1 HandlerAdapter. What you are basically doing is mimic the DispatcherServlet.

What you should do is lookup all `HandlerMapping`s and `HandlerAdapter`s and check if one of them has a match for the URL (i.e. returning a HandlerExecutionChain) and select the appropriate `HandlerAdapter` (calling the `supports` method). What you are doing is basically what the `DispatcherServlet` is doing.